# Which audio plugin interface standard should I use in Linux?

Tags: audio, plugin

We have developed a virtual instrument and now we are planning to port it to Linux. At previous I only know *LADSPA* interface. After a little bit more searching, I found *LV2* and *DSSI* are also audio plugin interfaces that are usable in Linux. So:

- If I only support one plugin interface, which one should I choose?
- Some place says *LV2* is successor of *LADSPA*, so does *LADSPA* already been completely replaced?